# How to ensure business rule integrity across multiple tables?

Tags: database-design, database-normalization

I am trying to ensure data integrity across multiple tables, this question is not DBMS specific, it is a theoretical question.  Here is the layout of the test tables:

```
Purchase
PurchaseID   CustomerID   ItemID    CustomerTypeDiscountID
         1           23        4                         2

Customer
CustomerID    Customer Name   CustomerTypeID
        23       Mike Smith                3
        24         John Doe                1

CustomerTypes
CustomerTypeID    CustomerTypeDescription
             1                        New
             2                        Old
             3                  Returning

Discounts
DiscountID   PercentDiscount
         1                 5
         2                10
         3                15
         4                20
         5                25
         6                30

CustomerTypeDiscounts
CustomerTypeDiscountID   CustomerTypeID   DiscountID
                     1                3            6
                     2                3            5
                     3                1            4
                     4                2            1
```

You see that in the Purchase table, the Discount for Purchase 1 is 25%, since Customer 23 (Mike Smith) is a Returning customer type and is able to receive Discount 5 (25%) through CustomerTypeDiscountID 2.

Returning customers could also get the 30% discount too.

But how can I ensure, using Foreign Key constraints, that in the Purchase table, the CustomerTypeDiscountID is always appropriate for the given CustomerID?  EG in the example, the CustomerTypeDiscountID in the Purchase record could only be 1 or 2 for this CustomerID, it would never be 3 or 4, etc, as those discounts are not appropriate for Customer 23's Customer Type.

Thanks.

Comment: That constraint cannot be enforced with a foreign key only. It could be enforced by a trigger (for instance checking when inserting or updating a purchase) or inside the application.

Comment: I am thinking that some constraint can't be described/enforced using Foreign Key constraints alone, it would need to be done using stored procedures, or through a trigger as you suggested.

Comment: I think this may be possible using a Check Constraint on the table, which would reference a Select statement (that joins CustomerTypeDiscounts, CustomerType, and Customer)

Comment: Check can only express inter-table constraints, not constraints among different tables.

Comment: If you are trying to do this as a modelling question, rather than using triggers, then you will need an additional table. Add `CustomerDiscount(CustomerDiscountID(PK), CustomerID, CustomerTypeID, CustomerTypeDiscountID)`  with an FK into`Customer(CustomerID,CustomerTypeID)` and then add `CustomerDiscountID` into the Purchase table, removing both `CustomerID` and `CustomerTypeDiscountID`. It will complicate things somewhat but that is often the tradeoff between implementing full referential integrity in the database, and handling some things in the app.